# when i want update profile banner using twitter api it shoes Image with unknown type provided

Tags: twitter

i am using twitter api to update banner. my api request is bellow

```
$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/update_profile_banner.json';
$requestMethod = 'POST';

$postfields = array(
    'width' => 520,
    'height'=> 260,
'banner' => $encoded_data
);

$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
echo $twitter->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
             ->setPostfields($postfields)
             ->performRequest();
```

when i sent a request it shows an error like bellow

```
"{"request":"\/1.1\/account\/update_profile_banner.json","error":"Image with unknown type provided"}"
```

let me now what was the wrong here.

thanks

Comment: How do you encoded this data? `$encoded_data`